# submit input text without submit button

Tags: html, forms

How can I submit a form when the user presses enter after typing in a value?

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com/search.php">
 <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="search">
</form>
```

Comment: I thought I had to add onSubmit() or something in the <form> tag?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add a submit button and set display to none

```
<input type="submit" style="display:none;" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You will need to use JQuery.

```
   $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
       //submit form
    }
});
```